# ionic 3 & AdMobFree: Tabs behind banner

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, admob, cordova-admob, ionic-tabs

I have made an app in ionic 3 and configured an AdMob banner at the bottom which works (almost) perfectly. Whenever I open the keyboard and close it afterwards, my tab menu at the bottom just slips behind that AdMob banner.

Screenshots:
[image: How it looks at the beginning and how it should be]

[image: Keyboard is open]

[image: Keyboard close and the tab navigation is gone]

I already tried to add margins or change the height of app-nav but all of this just resulted in weird, unwanted behaviour.

On the settings page, I also have a button which triggers the EmailComposer, when I close that Email afterwards, the exact same thing happens again.

When the AdMob ad is changed, the tabs just jump right back to their original location (where they should be). I also tried destroying/hiding the ad and then re-showing it when the keyboard is closed but this also, didn‘t change anything about the behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by subscribing to the keyboard didHide event and hide the banner for 100ms and re-show it just like here (app.component.ts):

```
        keyboard.didHide.subscribe(() => {
          admob.banner.hide().then(() => {
            setTimeout(() => admob.banner.show(), 100);
          });
        });
```

Comment: I was having this issue for a while and was not sure what was going on, found the solution thanks to this. Took a slightly different approach though, as i prefer not to rely on timers to do stuff. In my case i hide the banner on keyboard show event, and get the banner back on keyboard hide. Seems to work too. By the way, even thought this workaround works, I think this should be fixed in the admob library actually...

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding this line in config.xml.

```
<preference name="KeyboardResize" value="false" />
```